# How does raindrop velocity change in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I had a doubt about a question:

> Raindrops falling with terminal velocity strikes on a surface normally. Force exerted by the drops per unit area is $F$. if the number of drops striking the surface per unit time becomes one fourth and size of drops become double then force on the roof per unit area will be:
>
> Ans: $8F$

In this question, I have tried to use the concept of momentum by the formula $F=n(mv)$, where

- $n$ is the number of drops striking the surface per unit time
- $m$ is the mass of each drop
- $v$ is the velocity of the drop

I have figured out the $n$ which seems to be $n/4$ and $m$ to be $8m$ (assuming that the radius has became twice) in this question but not able to figure out how the velocity will change accordingly. Can anyone provide me some hints to how to proceed further?

Comment: What is meant by "size"?  Diameter, volume?

Comment: It  means that the radius has been doubled.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is $v_t$ ,  $V_{terminal}=2r^2(\rho-\sigma)/9\eta$ .

Now If we substitute this in equation we will get : $F = n_1m*2R^2_1(\rho-\sigma)/9\eta$.

$F_1/F_2=(n_1*r_1^2)/(n_2*r_2^2)$

$n_2=n_1/4$

$r_2=2*r_1$

M =$\rho V$

$Volume =4/3 \pi r^3$

$\therefore m2=8m_1$

We get

$8F_1=F_2$

Comment: How is it dimensionally incorrect? n has units of per second...

Comment: @DJohnM According to OP n is the number of drops falling per unit area

Comment: OP: "if the number of drops striking the surface per unit time"

Comment: @DJohnM Look at the bullet points. if the number of drops doesn't say n is the number of drops striking the surface.

Comment: The question is correct , i have written area in bullet points by mistake.I have corrected the same

Comment: @Guest2020 Okay  i will edit my answer.

Comment: @Guest2020 Can you re confirm your answer i am getting F1=F2 , otherwise i will have to delete it.

Comment: The answer is 8F only.

Comment: @Guest2020 I maybe missing something . Let's wait for a better answer.

Comment: The mass of the new drops is 8 times the old.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:

$$ F = \frac{\Delta P}{\Delta t} = nmv $$

you need to model the terminal velocity $v$.

Using:

$$ F_{\rm drag} \propto Av^2 = r^2v^2 = F_g \propto mg \propto r^3 $$

($A$ is cross-sectional area) you get:

$$ v \propto r^{\frac 1 2}$$

Then:

$$ F \propto n r^3r^{\frac 1 2} = nr^{\frac 7 2}$$

With $n\rightarrow n/4$ and $r \rightarrow 2r$:

$$ F \rightarrow (\frac 1 4)( 2^{\frac 7 2})F = 2\sqrt 2 F $$

If you assume viscous drag ($\propto v$), you can get an other $r^{\frac 1 2}$, for "4"...which is not 8.

Note that radar reflectivity (Rayleigh scattering) goes as $r^6$, so that goes up by a factor of 16....which is not the question.